# Fails to display certain columns data in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
date,unit_value,unit_value_cumulative,daily_growth_rate
2019/1/29,1.0139,1.0139,0.22
2019/1/30,1.0057,1.0057,-0.81
2019/1/31,1.0122,1.0122,0.65
2019/2/1,1.0286,1.0286,1.62
2019/2/11,1.0446,1.0446,1.56
2019/2/12,1.0511,1.0511,0.62
2019/2/13,1.0757,1.0757,2.34
2019/2/14,1.0763,1.0763,0.06
2019/2/15,1.0554,1.0554,-1.94
2019/2/18,1.0949,1.0949,3.74
2019/2/19,1.0958,1.0958,0.08
```

I have used the code below to plot them, but as you can see from out image, one column doesn't display on the plot.

```
df.plot(x='date', y=['unit_value', 'unit_value_cumulative', 'daily_growth_rate'], kind="line")
```

Output:

[image]

To plot `unit_value` only, I use: `df.plot(x='date', y=['unit_value'], kind="line")`

Out:

[image]

Anyone could help to figure out why it doesn't work out when I plot three columns on same plot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reproduced your results and it actually does work fine. In your case the values of the columns "unit_value" and  "unit_value_cumulative" are identical, which is why you only see the one in the front.
Besides of this problem your current data looks like you made a mistake when calculating the cumulative values.